# Stop process/program without admin rights - python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, process, operating-system, admin-rights

Is it possible to end/stop/pause/freeze a process/program running in background with python without having administrator rights on a Windows 7/8/10? If yes how? If no why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is yours, you can. Read about `taskkill`, `taskmgr` and `wmic`. Call them using `os.system`. Also, you may use `os.kill`, like:

```
os.kill (your-process-id, signal.SIGKILL)
```

(determining process ID requires reading process table, either parsing `tasklist` output or doing it via API)

If it is not yours, sorry... It means you should not kill it. But always, there is a way to kill the process - shut down the computer.

Answer (score 1):

That depends.

If you have the rights to end a process running in background, you can do so.

You can execute commands (e.g. for killing) in python like in cmd by using the call method of the subprocess module.

```
from subprocess import call
call(['command','with','parameters'])
```

The command to kill a program in Windows is `taskkill`.

So to kill iexplore.exe by its name u use `taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe` in cmd and `call(['taskkill','/F','/IM','iexplore.exe'])` in python code.

The documentation of call can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Manual of taskkill: https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb491009.aspx

Hope this helps ^^